# IP address and file manipulation python 2.6

Tags: python-2.6

I am new in python and I need your help to improve part of my script to be more sophisticate.

==================================== a.py

devices = ['x.x.x.x', 'x.x.x.x', 'x.x.x.x']

============================= MAIN CODE

from a import devices

for ip in devices:

```
 ssh connection
```

value = +1;

```
if value == 1: 

   open a specific file 
   run the commands from this file.

elif value == 2: 

   open a specific file 
   run the commands from this file.

elif value == 3: 

   open a specific file 
   run the commands from this file.
```

=============================================

Issue: For each IP address that it stored in a.py file, I need to run specific pack of commands. With the IF statement it is working fine, but if I add more IP address on a.py file need to append my code.

Thank you all.

Comment: Regardless of this question, if you're new to Python, I strongly suggest you use Python3.x instead of Python2.x. Python2 has been EOL for a while now and shouldn't be used anywhere anymore.

Comment: Regarding your question: Would it be possible to add your code sample enclosed in a coding block? You can click the curly-braces in the editor to format a code block.
Because currently it's hard to separate your code from what is extra info.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm interpreting your question correctly. Do correct me if I'm not.

You currently have a list with 3 ip addresses, and you handle them with three if-statements.
The problem is, that if you add more entries to your list, you will manually have to add more if-statements to your code?

If this assumption of your question is correct, then indeed. There is a better way of doing this:

```
devices = ['x.x.x.x', 'x.x.x.x', 'x.x.x.x']
for dev in devices:
   do_something(dev)
```

This will loop over all devices in your list, and execute the same code on each device.